# Inserir o retorno json dentro de divs separadas por <div> </div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um retorno do tipo **JSON** que estou tentando inserir dentro da div, mas é inserido todos um em cima do outro.

```
<!-- DIV que vai receber as informações -->
<section>
<div class="conteudo">
    <div class="foto"> FOTO </div>
    <div class="inf"> TITULO </div>
    <div class="inf"> DESCRICAO </div>
    <div class="inf"> PRECO </div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
    <div class="foto"> FOTO </div>
    <div class="inf"> TITULO </div>
    <div class="inf"> DESCRICAO </div>
    <div class="inf"> PRECO </div>
</div>
```

**Meu loop para tentar preencher as divs**

```
$("#menu li").click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "categoria/"+id,
    contentType: "charset=utf-8",
    }).done(function(output){
        json = $.parseJSON(output);
        $('.conteudo').empty();
        $.each(json, function(i, items){

            $('.conteudo').append(  
            items.fields['imagem'],+
            items.fields['nome_produto']+
            items.fields['descricao']+
            items.fields['preco_produto']
            ); 
        });
    });
return false;
```

});

Preciso colocar o conteudo de cada campo json em seu respectivo div.
Tentei inserir id ao inves de classes css para identificar. Tambem tentei utlizar os metodo .append(), .clone(), addClass(), appendTo mas sem sucesso. Se puderem me ajudar.

Comment: apenas uma dica, você pode fazer isto utilizando jsViews:
http://www.jsviews.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está a inserir sempre na mesma div, por isso o conteúdo está sendo sobreposto. Faça algo do tipo:

```
<!-- DIV que vai receber as informações -->
<div class="conteudos">
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="foto"> FOTO </div>
        <div class="inf"> TITULO </div>
        <div class="inf"> DESCRICAO </div>
        <div class="inf"> PRECO </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E então no jQuery:

```
$("#menu li").click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "categoria/"+id,
    contentType: "charset=utf-8",
    }).done(function(output){
        json = $.parseJSON(output);
        $.each(json, function(i, items){
            // Clona a div e armazena o conteudo em uma var temporária
            var clone = $('.conteudo:last').clone();
            // Aqui você seleciona a div conteudo baseado no idx (i)
            $('.conteudo:eq(i)').append(  
            items.fields['imagem'],+
            items.fields['nome_produto']+
            items.fields['descricao']+
            items.fields['preco_produto']
            );
            // Agora vc insere a div clonada dentro da div mãe
            // Aqui vale uma validação, caso seja a última iteração você não precisa inserir mais divs.
            $('.conteudos').append(clone);
        });
    });
return false;
});
```

Comment: Acho que faltou só adicionar a div clonada ao DOM, não?

Comment: Bem observado, eu havia inserido uma div envolvendo o HTML dele para inserir futuras divs, porém antes de postar me perguntei pq havia feito aquilo e removi.

Comment: Luis Henrique obrigado pela resposta. mas ainda não deu certo. Não entendi o uso  $('.conteudo:eq(i)').

Answer (score 0):

Crie um `id` para cada `append` que da certo,

exemplo: 
HTML

```
<div id='imagem'> Mostra a imagem </div>
<div id='title'> Mostra o titulo </div>
<div id='descricao'> Mostra a descriçao </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#imagem').append(items.fields['imagem']);
$('#title').append(items.fields['nome_produto']);
$('#descricao').append(items.fields['descricao']);
```

Comment: Isso ainda assim não é bom, pois caso existam mais de objetos com esses atributos, ainda existirão conflitos.

Comment: porque você não faz a criação dinamica das divs? desse jeito não precisa criar  id nem class, dentro dessa <div id='conteudo'> de um append assim var div += '<div>' + items.fields['imagem'] + </div>); e assim com as outras, ai voce ja da um append criando as divs